# Boot Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

Manifest:

```
         <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver android:name="CallReciver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">  

</action>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
               <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                    <action android:name=
                        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
                </intent-filter> 
            </receiver>
             <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
            <service
                android:enabled="true"
                android:name=".AlarmService">
            </service>
        </application>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
         </uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
        </uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS">
        </uses-permission>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS">
        </uses-permission>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
        </uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
        </uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
        </uses-permission>
```

Receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("Test","booot");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Receiver doesn't work. I turn off and on my device and nothing happens.
SMS And Call Receiver in this project work good.
SMS Receiver and CallReceviver - works good.
First post updated - added full manifest.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you have **HTC devic**e you also need to register for **"android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"**. So the entry in manifest should be:

```
    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

On my HTC, if I turn off the device and turn it on for a while I got QUICKBOOT_POWERON and no BOOT_COMPLETED.

If I turn off the device and remove the battery for a while - I got BOOT_COMPLETED after start.

Comment: Can we use emulator to try this?. I tried in emulator and device, but not working in both.

Answer (score 8):

Put permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Also try with full class name like <receiver android:name="com.something.OnBootReceiver">

Comment: put receiver in application tag

Comment: Don't unnderstand what you mean.

Comment: Your manifest is okay.Is the class OnBootReceiver is on the same package as SmsReceiver and CallReceiver?

Comment: try by adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Answer (score 3):

Also know that in Android >= 3.1 the app gets installed in 'stopped' state and will not get boot and shutdown events until the user 'does something' with the app at least once. See [this post on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892002/broadcastreceivers-in-ics)

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
   <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
        android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Cheers...!!!

Comment: Samsung A3 needed "enable" and "exported" flag to set to true, but on Huawei 6P and other 2 devices I think those were set to true by default. Thanks Rohit for the solution :)