# BOOT_COMPLETED never received

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, boot

Does every device send the BOOT_COMPLETED? I want to start an Activity on Boot Completed.

I put the following in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".BootFinished">            
    <intent-filter>                
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />           
    </intent-filter>        
</receiver>
```

Created the following class (receiver):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootFinished extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override        
    public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {               
          //do something like start an activity or service
        }

        try {
            PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
            Intent launch = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.afterboot");
            mContext.startActivity(launch);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } 
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find that the answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892002/broadcastreceivers-in-ics will fix your problem too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add full path and secondly add permission in your receiver.

   ```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.BootFinished"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">            
       <intent-filter>                
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />           
       </intent-filter>        
    </receiver>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, try putting the full path of your receiver in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons why broadcast reciever events could fail:

1. Receiver not declared in AndroidManifest.xml
   Declare the receiver in the Manifest-file:
2. Receiver in the Manifest xml is misspelled
   Android-System is case sensitive. So check your spelling and path is correct in the AndroidMainfest.xml
3. AVD running for a long time 
   Reset your avd/device

4.Also if your app is in moved to sdcard.Say you have registered for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED,the boot event is triggered even before the  mediascanner scans the sdcard.

and all the devices which run android sends BOOT_COMPLETE :P
Check again and try :)
all the best :)