# Broadcast Receiver not registering in Samsung

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, samsung-mobile

## Broadcast Receiver

I have an app which repeats an alarm everyday but somehow after rebooting its not registering the broadcast receiver for Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo (Android 4.4.2) but is working fine for Sony Xperia ZR (Android 5.0.2)

The manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sap.wish"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".StopAlarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

BootUpReceiver class

```
package com.sap.wish;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String tableName = "SETTINGS";
    final int ALARM_ID = 1;
    final String id = "ID";
    final String value = "VALUE";
    public BootUpReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        db = context.getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase("WTDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName
                + "(" + id + " INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                value + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(value));
            long savedmilli = Long.parseLong(result);
            Calendar savedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            savedCalendar.setTimeInMillis(savedmilli);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, intent2, 0);
            if (savedmilli != 0) {
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() > savedmilli)
                    savedmilli = savedmilli + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                db.execSQL("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + value + "='" + String.valueOf(savedmilli) + "' WHERE " + id + "=" + 1);
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, savedmilli, pendingIntent);
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your app is probably installed on the **External SD Card**, if so your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver will never get called.

to fix this add:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
```

to your receiver's intent filter like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Hope this will help you out, if it doesn't maybe change install location:

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

**edit**

Some devices got fast boot/reboot function and won't trigger the `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver, in that case try using:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Good luck

Comment: Hello I have one question here Android Kitkat does not support app to sd card so it should have worked in Android 4.4 and similarly shouldn't have worked in Android 5.0. But its vice-versa in my situation, can you explain why?

Comment: try after changing the receiver name to:  `<receiver android:name="(full package and name here)"` , got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080688/boot-completed-never-received)

Comment: Dunno if galaxy grand supports fast-reboot, but ifso you could try my edit