# Retained the Message Dialog after the Power on the Device in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have the Message Dialog and I wanted to retained the state of the dialog also wants to stay the dialog as it is.

Scenario 1 : I opened the Message Dialog after that I press the Power off the Device. When I press the Power on of the Device the dialog should stay as it as.

Scenario 2 : Also I wanted the Message Dialog when I rotate the Device. 
 I got the Success in Scenario 2 When I rotate the Device using the onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

Currently i dismiss the Dialog in OnDestroy to get the dialog open when I press the Power on the Device
before that I dismiss the Dialog onSavedInstancestate and Recreate the Dialog again.

so Please, get me suggestions against the Scenario 1. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your dialog show when you turn off the device save all data in `SharedPreference` or in database in `onDestroy` method and create a `BoradCastReciever` which will be triggered when you power ON the device. Create the dailog again and Restore all the data which you saved in `SharedPreference` or in database here .
See here how to make a `BootReceiver` 
[Boot Receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978403/boot-receiver-not-work)

Comment: Thanks.. But I dont want to use the BroadcastReceiver so Is there any alternative using the activity LifeCycle ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way (:

Comment: Then How can I retained the Dialog after the Power on the Device ?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you powering off the device completely. In your case If dialog does not retain it's state then try not to cancel it in `onDestroy` method. Or alternatively you can use an activity as a dialog which will retain it's state. `onSavInstanceState` is all you need in this case.