# AlarmManager is not triggered after complete bootup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, bootcompleted

I've used an alarmManager to send daily notification. Since alarmManager stops after restarting phone so I've created a BroadcastReceiver to trigger on BOOT_COMPLETE, still no success.
Even not getting toast.

**BroadcastRreceiver class**

```
package com.aman.dailynoti;

import...




public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    if ((intent.getAction()).equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        SharedPreferences mpreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
            int h=mpreferences.getInt("hour",14);

            int m=mpreferences.getInt("minute", 30);
        Calendar calendar=  Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,h);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,m);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

        Intent notiIntent = new Intent(context, Notification_Receiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, notiIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }

  }
 }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

 <application...>
       <receiver
        android:name="com.aman.dailynoti.BReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="breceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

     </application>
```

Comment: Check do you have **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>** permission is ther or not.

Comment: Yes I have it in manifest.

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441442/2557258

Answer (score 0):

Dont quote me on this but I believe android only gives a small window of time for your applications to do what they need to do on boot. If you want the user to receive notifications when not using the app look into push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you should use also intent filter `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` to recieve after restart

Comment: why? I have never seen that action before

Comment: i used it before and working with me when restarting

Comment: please check that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978403/boot-receiver-not-working

Comment: did you changed if statment in reciever to be like that if ((intent.getAction()).equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") || intent.getAction()).equals("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON") )

Comment: or you can remove it also your receiver will receive only actions which assigned

Comment: yes, I removed the if statement but still not working :(

Comment: what is your test device android version ?

Comment: if your android version 6.0 or + i believe that you have to request permissions at run time https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html